# Integrate - Why is the integration variable not local

Tags: scoping, language-design

I have noticed something odd:
Let

```
f[t_]:=Integrate[x, {x, 0, t}]
h[t_]:=Sum[x, {x, 0, t}]
```

Now, enter

```
Table[f[x], {x, 0, 5}]
Table[h[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

The first one fails, the second one does not. Consulting the documentation shows that the summation variable for `Sum` is local, but the integration variable for `Integrate` is not. There's even [an article](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DummyVariablesInMathematics.html) that mentions this fact.

My question is now: Is there any reason for this, i.e. any case where this 'not-scoping' is useful and not annoying? (Especially since they seem to have omitted this 'feature' for `Sum` or even `NIntegrate`)

Comment: Also, `Table`, `Do` and `Plot` scope, `Fit` does not. I always wanted to ask this myself.

Comment: Try `Array` instead of `Table`, like here `Array[ f[#]&, {5}]` and you'll see what may be the reason.

Comment: @Artes I already know why it is happening if that is what you're trying to explain. I am asking why it was implemented like this

Comment: I imagine, you may sometimes actually WANT to have your computation behave like Input/Output number 2 in the linked article. On the other hand, I'm not sure, why `Integrate` and `Sum` do not behave consistently.

Comment: I actually think this is in part a vagary of different development histories. But there is at least one important difference between the functions: `Sum` has both symbolic and procedural aspects to it (made more transparent by `Method` settings added several eyars ago). The procedural form really is akin to `Table ` and that argues strongly for scoping the variabler(s) of summation. `Integrate` does not have any analogous behavior, hence does not really warrant such scoping. It is akin to `Solve` in that respect.

Comment: Interesting, `Sum` admits such nonsense.. `Sum[ i , {i, i}] -> i (1 + i)/2` .. I expect if they started from scratch the way to resolve all this would be to insist on using formal parameters for integration variables and sum indices.

Comment: Thank you for Accepting my answer!  I didn't know if anyone would even see it.

Comment: I think I should thank you for giving me something to accept ;) (and for still taking the time to write such a nice answer to such an old question) - so thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see this primarily as an issue of localization but rather of assignment.  In a construct like [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) the variables are assigned values in some way.  This could potentially be done in several different ways, but a method like `Block` was chosen.  So we see:

```
Dynamic[x]
Table[Pause[1], {x, 10}];

(* changing Dynamic value *)
```

(I think this was probably chosen for its compatibility with standard [`For`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html) loop code.  [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) also changes the value of a variable, but uses something akin to [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html).)

Sum also assigns a value to a variable and a Block-like method was chosen for it as well:

```
Dynamic[x]
Sum[Pause[1], {x, 0, 10}];

(* changing Dynamic value *)
```

But what does [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) do?  It does not assign anything; there is no variable.

If nothing is assigned, no assignment needs to be localized.

```
Dynamic[x]
Integrate[Print[x]; Pause[1]; x, {x, 0, 5}]
```

> x
>
> x
>
> 25/2

There is no need to choose whether to use `Block`, or `Module`, or something else (`With`?) as nothing is iteratively changed.  Rather `x` is merely a *specification*, not a variable.

- Expecting a scoping construct here would be like expecting one
  on `x` in `Collect[a x + b y + c x, x]` as that too is a specification.

There is a related construct that *does* use variables: [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html).  And guess what?  It works like `Table` and `Sum` do:

```
Dynamic[x]
fn[_?NumericQ] := Pause[1]
NIntegrate[fn[x], {x, 0, 15}];

(* changing Dynamic value *)
```